# I got a Sum() where a.name = b.name, I want to select the name of the highest Sum() : How?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I now I'm not clear with this question, but I have the following tables :

```
------------------------------
-- Recipe ----- Ingredients --
------------------------------
-- ID        -  ID          --
-- Name      -  Name        --
-- Cost      -  Cost        --
-- Calories  -  Calories    --
--           -  RecipeName  --
------------------------------
```

And I created this procedure

```
DELIMITER !!!
CREATE PROCEDURE RecipeCost()
BEGIN
SELECT Ingredients.RecipeName,
       MAX(( SELECT SUM(Ingredients.Cost)
             FROM Ingredients
             WHERE Recipe.Name = Ingredients.RecipeName)) AS Price   
FROM Ingredients
JOIN Recette
WHERE Recette.Name= Ingredients.RecipeName;

END !!!
```

It displays correctly the highest cost, but I can't manage to display the Name of the Recipe associated with this cost.

Do you have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gets the cost for each recipe:

```
select i.recipename, sum(i.cost)
from ingredients i
group by i.recipename;
```

To get the highest cost . . .

```
select i.recipename, sum(i.cost) as total_cost
from ingredients i
group by i.recipename
order by total_cost desc
limit 1;
```

The join to the recipes table is unnecessary, because the name is in the ingredients table.

Comment: Awesome ! Now I can select only the highest recipe and show it, thank you !

Just have a last question, do you have any idea on how to show the Highest AND the Lowest ones in a single procedure ?

Comment: @Prototype . . . In MySQL, this is probably most easily done with two queries (or `union all` between two subqueries).

Comment: Added an Union with "Order By total_cost limit 1" and it works like a charm. Thank you once again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the usage of `max`. `sum` already makes the subquery resulting in a single value. Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT r.name, SUM(i.cost)
FROM Recipe r
  JOIN Ingredients i ON r.name = i.recipeName
GROUP BY r.name
```

Comment: God, the Group By .. Forgot that. Thank you ! I just need to select only the highest / lowest values now, but htat's easy ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by RecipeName and use aggregation SUM to get the desired result. In order to get both max and min use different ordering and Union the results.. 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3c470/6

```
(select i.RecipeName, sum(i.cost) cost
from ingredients i
group by i.RecipeName
order by cost desc
limit 1)
UNION
(select i.RecipeName, sum(i.cost) cost
from ingredients i
group by i.RecipeName
order by cost 
limit 1);
```